# Script Hosting (API to Database)

Tags: database, api, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, infrastructure

I am currently creating a react native + expo application upon which essentially each page makes an API call, which is a lot of API calls. I have this app also connected to firebase for different information. The things is, each of these pages don't update more than once or twice a day for the most part, so I really don't want the End User to be calling the API that much either.

My question is, is there a way to write and host a script that will continuously run that knows to call this API once every hour (or so) and then rewrite to the firebase db from which I can then only need to pull from the database as compared to having each user individually making dozens of API calls.

Please let me know! I have spent days on google and am no closer than I was before. I'm also willing to change my set up from firebase if it is not possible to accomplish that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Cloud Functions scheduled trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run code periodically that can make changes to your database.